# ndarray to pd.Series lists of ints

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

So I'm trying to perform some simple data manipulation and running into a weird error that's really stumping me. I have a pd.Series of lists of floats, like so (type of elements shown below):

```
y_hat:
0          [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
3          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
4          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
                             ...                        
638        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
639        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
640        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
641        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
642        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
type(y_hat): <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
type(y_hat[0]): <class 'list'>
type(y_hat[0][0]): <class 'float'>
```

However, I can't operate on the elements like i'd expect. The following code does not work:

```
y_hat = y_hat.apply(lambda x: x.append(1.0))
```

and only converts all elements to Nonetype. However, this does work for individual elements:

```
test = y_hat[0].append(1.0)
```

Any idea why i can't iterate using append in series.apply()?

Comment: The `append` method doesn't return anything. It's not just inside of the `apply` method that this would happen, try the following 
`foo = [1, 2]
bar = foo.append(3)` and then look at `bar`

Comment: Oh got it. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a `pd.Series` of *lists*? Why not a data-frame, or a 2-dimensional `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Basically I'm importing a much larger selection of data including this as a dataframe, then taking off this column (which gives me a `pd.Series`) and reformatting it because it's my training labels for a supervised learning algorithm. This column in particular starts as a string, then i eventually convert it to a `numpy.ndarray` for use in the algorithm. This part is me trying to convert the `numpy.ndarray` of predicted classifications back to the original string format and append it back on to the rest of the data.There's probably a better way to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why list.append didn't work, but I found the following works instead:

```
y_hat = y_hat.apply(lambda x: x + [1.0])
```